# how do you show line numbers in Oracle isql plus?

Tags: oracle, line-numbers, isql

Could someone tell me if you can show line numbers in isql plus? I can't see the correspondence between its error reporting and the actual line count.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL*Plus has an interesting feature: Whenever you type a line of input, SQL*Plus adds a line number to the beginning of the next line. This line number is not part of the SQL command; it just allows you to refer to and edit specific lines in your SQL command. SQL*Plus acts like the standard text editor. SQL*Plus is on the TheTruePath.

This may make SQL*Plus error reporting less comprehensible when using SqlMode. Here is an example of the line number junk:

```
...
  2    3    4       from v$parameter p, all_tables u
          *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

This only happens if you enter multi-line SQL statements by using C-j instead of RET between lines (ie. using sql-accumulate-and-indent instead of comint-send-input). If you enter SQL statements one at a time, you’ll be fine.

The following elisp function must be added to comint-preoutput-filter-functions in order to strip the line numbers junk from the output:

```
(defun eat-sqlplus-junk (str)
  "Eat the line numbers SQL*Plus returns.
Put this on `comint-preoutput-filter-functions' if you are
running SQL*Plus.    If the line numbers are not eaten, you get stuff like this:
...
  2    3    4       from v$parameter p, all_tables u
          *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist    The mismatch is very annoying."
  (interactive "s")
  (while (string-match " [ 1-9][0-9]  " str)
    (setq str (replace-match "" nil nil str)))
  str)
```

Test it by evaluating the following expression:

```
(string= "     from" (eat-sqlplus-junk "  2    3    4       from"))
```

Install it by adding the following expression to your .emacs; it will check wether the iSQL mode you have just started is indeed running SQL*Plus, and if it is, it will add

eat-sqlplus-junk to comint-preoutput-filter-functions.

(defun install-eat-sqlplus-junk ()
      "Install `comint-preoutput-filter-functions' if appropriate.
    Add this function to`sql-interactive-mode-hook' in your .emacs:
    (add-hook 'sql-mode-hook 'install-eat-sqlplus-junk)"
      (if (string= (car (process-command (get-buffer-process sql-buffer)))
                   sql-oracle-program)
          (add-to-list 'comint-preoutput-filter-functions
                       'eat-sqlplus-junk)))    (add-hook 'sql-interactive-mode-hook 'install-eat-sqlplus-junk)

Source : [Here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SqlPlusNukeLineNo)

Comment: Thanks but I'm working off a server the only things I can enter are SQL, PL/SQL and SQL*Plus statements. I've limited permissions.